# how to disable auto tab after pressing enter and losing focus of textbox

Tags: xaml, uwp, c++-cx

I have an Event Handler for a keyDownEvent in a TextBox. Now when I press Enter this Event Handler changes the Visibility to Collapsed and the TextBox hides. the Problem with it is that this obviously unfocus the TextBox and foucus sth. else in my App. How can I disable this autofocus of another element and focus nothing?

I have tried the following but i am really screwed.

```
if (e->Key == Windows::System::VirtualKey::Enter) {
    this->mode = ITEM_MODE::SELECT; // will Change Visibility to Collapsed
    FocusManager::TryMoveFocus(FocusNavigationDirection::None);
    e->Handled = true;          
}
```

Thanks for your help! <3

Comment: There is always a foreground app (including the Desktop) and that app always has a focussed element so what you ask isn’t possible

Comment: @MickyD but what is focused when my app is starting?

Answer (score 0):

> how to disable auto tab after pressing enter and losing focus of textbox

Derive from official document,

> `UseSystemFocusVisuals` used to  get or set a value that indicates whether the control uses focus visuals that are drawn by the system or those defined in the control template.

You could set control [`UseSystemFocusVisuals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.usesystemfocusvisuals)  property as `False`. Then next control will not be focused by system.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="RootLayout" IsTapEnabled="False" >
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="44" KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" />
    <Button Content="FouceElement" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False"/>
    <Button Content="NextBtn" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: But usually you want to have focus visuals enabled (e.g. when pressing `Tab` key), but the question is how to programatically get to the state when no focus indicator is visible on the screen (just like when you start the application - focus visuals appear only after you click something or press `Tab`).

Answer (score 0):

In case you just don't want the auto-focused item to have focus indicator shown, you can change the `Focus` type to `FocusState.Pointer`.

Example (C#):

```
object focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();
((Control)focusedElement).Focus(FocusState.Pointer); // This will hide focus indicator
```